# Limit number of chips display

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angularjs-material

I'd like to display only a the first three chips of a list, and put a marker that there are more to see (like three dots for example).

Is there a way to do so with the `<md-chips>` directive ?

I'd prefer specify that I'm talking about a read-only chips list, not editable. I've tried with `md-max-chips` but it only controls the add of new chips.

Some piece of code :

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="start center">
    <md-chips ng-model="mylist" readonly="true"></md-chips>
</div>
```

How I would like it to be displayed (the header is not in the code)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [this solution](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eVwQZr?editors=1010):

**HTML:**

```
<md-chips ng-model="ctrl.visible" readonly='true' ng-click="ctrl.select($event)">
</md-chips>
```

**Javascript:**

```
self.fruitNames = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange', 'Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3', 'Test4'];

var i = 0;
function ModifyVisible(){
  self.visible = self.fruitNames.slice(0, (3 * ++i));
  if(self.fruitNames.length > self.visible.length)
    self.visible.push('...');
}
ModifyVisible();

self.select = function($event) {             
  if($event.path[0].textContent == '...')
    ModifyVisible();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may going to try to manipulate your list object like in this **[codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WMqagx)**. The last item is an placeholder item. You should manipulate your list before rendering / binding to view.

```
self.vegObjs = [
  {
    'name' : 'Broccoli',
    'type' : 'Brassica'
  },
  {
    'name' : 'Cabbage',
    'type' : 'Brassica'
  },
  {
    'name' : 'Carrot',
    'type' : 'Umbelliferous'
  },
  {
    'name' : '...',
    'type' : ''
  }
];
```